# PHP - RFC3339 date to "friendly" date (google calendar api)

Tags: php, datetime, date, formatting, format

I need to convert a date from RFC3339 format (that is returned by google calendar api) to a format such as "1st October,  5pm" in PHP.

If I am correct, format for RFC3339 is:  2010-12-01T17:00:00.000-02:00

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use PHP's amazing [`strtotime`](http://php.net/strtotime) and [`date`](http://php.net/date) functions.

```
$RFC = "2010-12-01T17:00:00.000-02:00";
$date = date('jS F, ga', strtotime($RFC)); // 1st December, 5pm
```

UPDATE: If you have PHP >= 5.2, you can use the [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class.

```
$RFC = "2010-12-01T17:00:00.000-02:00";
$date = new DateTime($RFC);
$dateStr = $date->format('jS F, ga'); // 1st December, 5pm
```

Comment: yes, I tried the DateTime class before asking the question, but I dont have PHP >=5.2 , so I didnt know how to do it :) Thanks

Comment: Actually I found an issue with this.

if I have: 2010-12-31T17:00:00.000-02:00     

(that is 5pm, time zone -2)

date('ga', strtotime("2010-12-31T17:00:00.000-02:00"));

I get back 1PM.  Is there some server configuration I need to do like set time zone or am I missing something?
Thanks

Comment: @Daniel take a look at this.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Comment: thanks,  so I have to parse the "-02:00" part and set the timezone ?

Comment: @Daniel: I'm not sure... you can try that.

Comment: worked for this RFC3339 timestamp when all other strtotimes wouldnt. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use [strtotime()](http://php.net/strtotime) to convert to a UNIX timestamp. Then [date()](http://php.net/date) to format the output